# Random change of input language

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support

Ubuntu 21.10 and earlier

1. I have English and Russian layout.
2. Mostly I use English in all windows and sometime Russian in Firefox.
3. I can start work at morning with English layout. And suddenly I have Russian layout in the code editor after changing many different windows.
4. I noticed it especially when I have screen sharing session and I don't use Russian layout for an hour and suddenly I have Russian layout in the terminal.
5. Sometimes it happen as often as 1 of 5 times of change different windows.

### How I tried to resolve it.

1. I tried to change order in the input configuration. It didn't help
2. I set "the same layout for all windows" what is default. It didn't help

### What I want.

I want it the same language for all windows without random switches.

1. I want language input do not change randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most probable explanation is that you are inadvertently hitting the Next Input Source keyboard shortcut. The default for this is Super + Space, ie. pressing the Windows key and the spacebar at the same time, which is pretty easy to hit by accident.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html.en for details.

Possible solutions include (a) being more careful while typing in order to avoid hitting key combinations by accident or (b) changing the keyboard shortcut to something less error prone.

Comment: It sounds as true. Exept some reasone it switch source with ctrl+shift+tab with which I am switching to the privious window. I use Ubuntu Budgie btw. The key behaviour is different here what is annoying. I will try to identify why it happens

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it answers your question. It helps other readers who may have the same question.

Comment: I think it can be related that I use Ubuntu Budgie. I also have problem that after restart sometime I can use only one language. After I just rearange them in the settings all become normal again